# Dual of identity relation?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-language, philosophy-of-logic

Does anyone have any intuitions about what the dual of the identity relation might be? I.e. is there a 'natural' concept expressed by a statement such as 'it is not the case that a is not identical to b', where this latter statement can be taken to express a statement dual to the statement 'a is identical to b'?

Comment: What do you mean by "'natural' concept"? And, did you mean to use two 'not's in the first of the two statements?

Comment: In classical logic this is not a question.  Do you mean an Intuitionist double negative -- "It cannot be reliably known whether a and b are different"?  Some nonstandard analysis relies on 'infinitesimals' or 'spatial monads' injected in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like the complement of the [apartness relation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation).  Apartness focuses on distinguishing things, instead of identifying them.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, we would tend to have a strong logical presumption that `a` is not identical `b` based on one being called "a" and the other called "b" because the difference in names implies a spatial and/or temporal difference in the conditions under which each is encountered. The burden of proof falls on those claiming ["Hesperus is Phosphorus."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frege%27s_Puzzle)

The premise that classic philosophic logic has some strong principle of identity is a bit suspect in itself. The [Ship of Theseus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) has been an important paradox since the early days of philosophy.

The real problem is that "the same" requires disambiguation if we're talking in a logical context. Thus formal languages in computing often have multiple predicates for sameness [e.g Lisp's `eq`, `eql`, and `equal`].

Pierce's [pragmatic maxim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_maxim) perhaps points the way. `a` is not identical `b` if and only if the effects of `a` are not identical to the effects of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious logical answer would be to negate the expression, identical, (ie.  not identical).  Another possibility is, "is different" (ie. A is different from B).

Comment: Note that the question was not about the _contradictory_ of the identity relation, but about its _dual_. In classical logic, as implied by @jobermark in his comment, identity is _self-dual_. My answer, on the other hand, allows for a constructive stance, according to which such self-duality of identity does not necessarily hold.